# Sklearn Imputer Pipeline run on X_test values when calling predict?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, imputation

If I have a pipeline like this in Sklearn:

```
steps = [('imputation', Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)),
            ('Ridge', Ridge(alpha=0.1, normalize=True))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
pipeline.fit(X, y)

# Will the imputer be run on the X_test values here?
pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Will the imputer be run on the X_test values?

Comment: Well, strange question... Since you do specify `X_test` as an argument, where else could it run on??

Comment: It runs on the X_train when the model is fit. So calling predict will also impute the test data?

Comment: All the data processing needs to be done on both train and test samples..if you split X and y to get train and test after pipeline fitting then no. Otherwise yes.

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for in the sklearn Pipeline predict docs. Calling predict does apply the pipeline transformations

Comment: Just keep in mind that it will not learn the values from the test data. In this cas, the `most_frequent` value learnt from the train data (`X`) will be just applied to the missing values of `X_test`.